# i have two column in text file. when i search one word from 1st column 2nd column data should be visible in python

Tags: python

I have two column in the text file. While searching a 1st column word, its corresponding 2nd column word should display as output.

when I search the word "isliy",all respective words are showing like this:

```
{'isliy': 'isliye', 'islia': 'isliye', 'islie': 'isliye', 'jayenga': 'jayenge', 'bnaya': 'banaya', 'bnaye': 'banaye', 'dikhaye': 'dikhayein', 'haiiii': 'hai', 'lalach': 'laalach', 'upr': 'upar', 'hora': 'ho  raha', 'tmhe': 'tumhe', 'Aacha': 'Acha', 'naii': 'nahi', 'jakkas': 'jhakkas', 'tmhi': 'tum  hi', 'sbhi': 'sabhi', 'kum': 'kam', 'sunder': 'sundar', 'ghnte': 'ghante', 'jaooo': 'jao', 'tufan': 'toofaan', 'mei': 'mein', 'glti': 'galti', 'gayee': 'gaye', 'gli': 'gali', 'k': 'ke', 'drr': 'dar', 'bhut': 'bahut', 'bhuk': 'bhook', 'bhul': 'bhool', 'krliya': 'kar  lia', 'glt': 'galat', 'drd': 'dard', 'bkwas': 'bakwaas', 'Kon': 'kaun', 'dekta': 'dekhta', 'dekte': 'dekhte', 'jayrga': 'jayega', 'smjhti': 'samjhti', 'rahti': 'rehti', 'rahte': 'rehte', 'smjhte': 'samjhte', 'Gggjjjbb': 'gajab', 'krwana': 'karvana', 'niii': 'nahi', 'krwane': 'karvane', 'achchha': 'acha', 'bejna': 'bhejna', 'Achi': 'acchi', 'Apko': 'aapko', 'bhuaji': 'buaji', 'jesi': 'jaisi', 'me': 'mein', 'ma': 'Maa', 'mt': 'mat', 'dimag': 'dimaag', 'dimak': 'deemak', 'jayda': 'zyada', 'aukat': 'aaukaat', 'aaap': 'aap', 'Abb': 'Ab', 'Abi': 'Abhi', 'pitai': }
```

In the below code:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
d = {}
search = raw_input("search :")
read_file = open('/Users/abhishek/Desktop/data_merged.txt','r')
split = [line.strip() for line in read_file]
for line in split:
    l1.append(line.split()[0].strip())
    l2.append('  '.join(line.split()[1:]).strip())
d= dict(zip(l1,l2))
print d
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    if key.startswith(search):
        print d[key]
```

When I search "isliy"  - only "isliye" should come.how to do that?

Comment: Why are you using `startswith` here? If you want to look for a key with complete match, use an equality operator `==`.

Comment: @Austin In fact, it wouldn't even require `==`, much less iteration over the `dict` (thereby defeating the point of using a `dict` to begin with). Simply:

`if key in d:
    print d[key]`

Comment: @user1093967 understand that `if key in d:` is always true and it prints all values in `d`. He wants value of a particular key only if I am not wrong.

Comment: thank you it woked.

Comment: yes Austin "== "  point is right..@Austin

Comment: @Austin Sorry, I meant `if search in d: print d[search]`.

Comment: (Because there's no reason to iterate over the `dict`, `key` wouldn't even be defined. I just mixed it up in a hurry previously.)

Comment: @user1093967  your point is also right. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
d = {}
search = raw_input("search :")
read_file = open('/Users/abhishek/Desktop/data_merged.txt','r')
split = [line.strip() for line in read_file]
for line in split:
l1.append(line.split()[0].strip())
l2.append('  '.join(line.split()[1:]).strip())
d= dict(zip(l1,l2))
#print d

#"use this"
'''for key,value in d.iteritems():
if key==search:
    print d[key]'''
#"or this"
if search in d:
print d[search]
```